# Can I use a list of blog ping services for a portal?

Tags: seo, ping

I'm setting up a list of ping services for a portal.
It has a blog, forum, articles, restaurants, hotels and many other information, so it is far beyond a blog.

I have a [list of standard ping services for WP blogs](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-ping-list) - but I do not know if this should be literally only for blogs.

My questions are:

1. Is it recommended to ping blog services from a portal, such as http://blogsearch.google.com/ping/RPC2?
2. Are there any penalties for sites that are not recognized as blogs?
3. Is there some list of ping services for regular websites and not only blogs?

Thanks!